# Passing arguments to a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I'm getting the message error

> **TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)**

for the code described below:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(arg1,arg2,arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
    def some_function(self):
        print "it works: " + arg1 + arg2 + arg3

w=Worker("a","b","c")
w.some_function()
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `def __init__(self, arg1,arg2,arg3):`. You'll also need to change the `print` statement in `some_function` to

```
print "it works: " + self.arg1 + self.arg2 + self.arg3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def __init__(self,arg1,arg2,arg3):
```

Comment: after updating with your sugestion, im having: 
NameError: global name 'arg1' is not defined. should i set global arg1, arg2 , arg3 ?

Comment: Ah, thanks, i figured that out after writing the comentary. thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument expected for any class function should always be `self`.

Well, the name is unimportant, but that's the meaning of it.

So your function definintion should look like:

```
def __init__(self,arg1,arg2,arg3): 
    self.arg1 = arg1 
    self.arg2 = arg2 
    self.arg3 = arg3
```

Comment: This is only true for the methods of instances of a class. Not if you use the methods directly on the class: `Worker.some_function(self)` is equivalent to `w.some_function()`

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer so the function shouldn't be defined as `def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3)`??

Comment: They should. I'm just saying because you said it's true for all methods. There are also classmethods that don't take the self argument.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer class method is a confusing term also. Since there is a @classmethod decorator that passes the `class` as the first argument.

Comment: @rantanplan I just call them methods (the ones that take self as first arg) and class-methods (the ones using the `@classmethod` decorator).

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I get what you're saying, but there are the instance methods(self as 1st arg), the class methods(cls as 1st arg) and static methods(no 1st arg). Just saying that it is easy to get mixed up and that's a python issue and not your fault.